How can i simulate a custom file extension
I'm programming a software using python that loads and saves the information into PDFs and i want to custom the exported files to be '.[software_name]' instead of '.pdf'. Let's say the software_name is 'potato'.
At the beginning i was trying to rename the file 'file.pdf' to 'file.potato' when exporting and then rename the file 'file.potato' to 'file.pdf'. But changing the extension of a file doesn't change its type or contents as one comment told me so if you open 'file.potato' as a pdf the pdf reader will read it without any problems.
I was thinking in open the pdf in rb mode and write a string finished in \n and then save the content as 'file.potato' so the pdf reader should not be able to read it like a normal pdf even if you try to read as a pdf. To read it again i would revert the changes in binary mode to use the pdf content in my software.
Do you have any better ideas on how to do it?

The idea is later to implement a method to revert the situation so the pdf can be readed again

Don't post images of code, data or error messages. They can't be searched and it's difficult to set up a test environment. See [ask]

Changing the extension of a file doesn't change its type or contents - same as you can't pull the Fiat badge off your car and stick on a Ferrari one - it will still be a Fiat and won't go any faster.

Removing the first byte may make it more difficult to read, but not unreadable.  All of the actual data is still there.  What is the actual underlying goal and why?

@KJ How are you going to revert deleting everything else?

What is the ultimate purpose here? If you want to positively prevent folks from reading it, use a password. If you want to merely make it "more difficult" to read, a simple way is to reverse the order of the bytes in the file. If you use that method, your obfuscation is the same as your de-obfuscation, no need to write 2 lots of code. Each invocation converts either obfuscated to de-obfuscated, or de-obfuscated to obfuscated.

It's for the project management subject where i'm developing a code with some other students and our product owner demand a custom extension so yeah, prevent folks from reading and have another appearance in file explorer.

PDF files are binary, not text. You need to open it in binary mode.

@KJ that may all be true, but if you are using Python's text mode to open the PDF, as OP did in the code screen capture they originally posted but edited out, it gets corrupted. You need to open it using Python's binary mode to be able to process it.

In fact, you point to the problem yourself: "All PDF will work as text as long as they are decided by the reader correctly", and that starts with using Python's binary mode on file open.

@KJ that all seems like good advice, and suggests I misunderstood your first comment, sorry about that.

Yeah, its the better solution that i test so thanks
